# Pylint can't find SQLAlchemy query member

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pylint

I have a Flask (v0.10.1) application using Flask-SQLAlchemy (v2.0) and I'm trying to configure Pylint to check it. Running with Python 3.4.2.

First error was:

```
 Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'Table' member (no-member)
```

And I fixed this one ignoring the check for member attributes on SQLAlchemy:

```
ignored-classes=SQLAlchemy
```

But I'm having a problem with the query member on entities:

```
Class 'UserToken' has no 'query' member (no-member)
```

Is there any way to fix this issue without having to ignore no-member errors on every query call?

---

Flask bootstrap:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__)
db.init_app(app)
app.run()
```

UserToken entity:

```
from app import db

class UserToken(db.Model):
    user_token_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    token_auth = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False, index=True)
```

The controller:

```
from entities import UserToken

token = UserToken.query.filter(
    UserToken.token_auth == token_hash,
).first()
```

Comment: Flake8 is an option but for now I added `query` to `generated-members` of Pylint.

Answer (score 61):

## Solution

`pip install pylint-flask`

`pip install pylint-flask-sqlalchemy`

**Load the installed plugin.**

For example, if you use VS code, please edit settings.json file as follows:

`"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy", "pylint_flask"]`

## Optional

If having other warnings, define remaining members in `generated-members` in `pylintrc` file.

Comment: After doing that I still get the same errors like `Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'Column' member (no-member)`

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me.. perhaps there are other settings that need to be set

Comment: This doesn't / shouldn't work,. Read the plugin source code, it's nothing to do with sqlalchemy. Only `ignored-modules` or `generated-members` help.

Comment: for me the following works: `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint-flask"]`

Comment: I had to use `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy"]` (note the underscores), otherwise pylint throws an `ImportError: No module named 'pylint-flask-sqlalchemy'`, furthermore it did not work with only adding `pylint-flask`, I needed the plugin `pylint-flask-sqlalchemy` as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/58979882/4112816

Comment: @Mirko I got the same error. When I checked my packages it's named "pylint_flask" with an underscore

Comment: This helps with flask-sqlalchemy members, but not with sqlalchemy members.

Comment: Only `pylint_flask_alchemy` is necessary, `pylint_flask` is irrelevant. However, it seems to no longer work since SQLAlchemy 1.4.0 (specifically commit 2665a0c4cb3e94e6545d0b9bbcbcc39ccffebaba, which removes `Session.public_methods`, which `pylint_flask_alchemy` makes use of). It would actually be quite easy to adapt `pylint_sql_alchemy` to this change, but it seems it's no longer maintained (last commit was on 2020-01-14) :(

Comment: I meant `pylint_flask_sqlalchemy` in the comment above, obviously (I accidentally omitted `sql`). Also, I see now that work is actually still ongoing on it, it's just that it has moved to GitHub. But the published version is still 0.2.0; I guess/hope things will work properly once the next version (seems it will be 1.0.0) is released.

Answer (score 23):

Any class you declare as inheriting from `db.Model` won't have `query` member until the code runs so Pylint can't detect it.

The workaround for this besides ignoring no-member errors on every `query` call is to add `query` on the `generated-members` list in a Pylint config file since it is a member that will only be created at runtime.

When you run Pylint, it will search for a configuration file as stated in its [documentation](http://docs.pylint.org/run.html):

> You can specify a configuration file on the command line using the --rcfile option. Otherwise, Pylint searches for a configuration file in the following order and uses the first one it finds:
>
> 1. `pylintrc` in the current working directory
> 2. If the current working directory is in a Python module, Pylint searches up the hierarchy of Python modules until it finds a pylintrc file. This allows you to specify coding standards on a module-by-module basis. Of course, a directory is judged to be a Python module if it contains an `__init__.py` file
> 3. The file named by environment variable `PYLINTRC`
> 4. if you have a home directory which isn’t `/root`:
>
>    1. `.pylintrc` in your home directory
>    2. `.config/pylintrc` in your home directory
> 5. `/etc/pylintrc`

So if you don't have a config and you want a system wide default config for pylint you can use `pylint --generate-rcfile > /etc/pylintrc`. This will generate a  commented configuration file according to the current configuration (or the default if you don't have one) that you can edit to your preferences.

p.s.: `generated-members` on a config file is the right way to deal with this warning, as it's said by the commented config

```
  # List of members which are set dynamically and missed by pylint inference
  # system, and so shouldn't trigger E0201 when accessed. Python regular
  # expressions are accepted.
```

Comment: Do you mean that adding all used members of sql_alchemy is the correct way to deal with this? This is both tedious and possibly masking further warnings of similar member names of different classes. Not the best of way in my opinion.

Answer (score 20):

I meet the same issue when using flask_sqlalchemy.
my solution is:

```
pylint --generate-rcfile>~/.config/pylintrc
```

and then find the

```
ignored-modules
```

line, rewrite it to:

```
ignored-modules=flask_sqlalchemy
```

all E1101 errors are gone.

Remeber to read the comment:

```
# List of module names for which member attributes should not be checked
# (useful for modules/projects where namespaces are manipulated during runtime
# and thus existing member attributes cannot be deduced by static analysis. It
# supports qualified module names, as well as Unix pattern matching.
```

Comment: Are all these commands we have to run , because the first one refused

Answer (score 12):

## Warning: Do not just `--load-plugins pylint-flask`

- By doing this (using *dashes* instead of *underscores*) you will just **disable pylint altogether**! This is because the `--load-plugins` needs the name of the python package *to be imported*. You can check this on command line (will get ImportError) if you do so. Pylinting in VS Code is nastier since you *will not get any visible errors*. Instead, you will have zero linting errors even if your code would have some linting problems.

### pylint-flask will not work

[pylint-flask](https://github.com/jschaf/pylint-flask) is a good plugin, but it is not even meant to tackle this problem! You can [see the source code](https://github.com/anybox/pylint_flask_sqlalchemy/blob/master/pylint_flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py) for yourself. There is no mentions about Flask-SQLAlchemy; it is only designed to fix issues (false positives) with Flask.

### pylint-flask-sqlalchemy

The [pylint-flask-sqlalchemy](https://github.com/anybox/pylint_flask_sqlalchemy) [was created](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1973#issuecomment-512748934) to fix the pylint false positives with Flask-SQLAlchemy. After installing with

```
pip install pylint-flask-sqlalchemy
```

one should add it with<sup>1</sup>

```
# NOT: "pylint-flask-sqlalchemy"
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy"]
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>Applies directly only for **VS Code**. With other IDEs or command line, use the same arguments in the same order.</sup>

### pylint-flask with pylint-flask-sqlalchemy

If used together, for some reason

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask", "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy"]
```

**will not work** but

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy", "pylint_flask"]
```

does. So, presumably, the pylint-flask must be loaded *after* pylint-flask-sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 9):

The one that worked for me was switching to `flake8` python linter. Below are the steps:

1. Open VSCode and run `Ctrl+shift+P`(For Windows Users)
2. In the VSCode Search prompt, type `Python:Select Linter`. You will see a list of all Linters and select flake8.
3. If you do not have flake8 installed as a VScode extension for pylint, it will prompt you to install it. Proceed and install it.

Comment: it worked for me too. No solution worked for pylint

Comment: Spoiler alert: I unexpectedly get lots of hot new red wavy lines simply because flake8 linting is different from pylint linting. It was really **unexpected**.

Comment: I like this. Don't want to spend time configuring linters :-)

Answer (score 8):

Use pylint plugin pylint-flask-sqlalchemy

```
pip install pylint_flask_sqlalchemy
```

And in your settings.json of VisualCode

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask_sqlalcheny"]
```

Comment: spelling mistake `pylint_flask_sqlalcheny` should be `pylint_flask_sqlalchemy`

Answer (score 7):

After trying a lot of these options, plugins and adding query and all. The only solution that erased those scoped_session errors was using:

1. `pylint --generate-rcfile > pylintrc`
2. look for the ignored_classes and add scoped_session after the comma, leave no space
3. Run `pylint` on your module again.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version of joeforker's answer that dynamically adds all public methods from the `Session` object back into a `scoped_session`'s locals at lint-time, instead of hardcoding a few well-known method names.

Define `{path}/{to}/pylintplugins.py`:

```
import sys

from astroid import MANAGER, scoped_nodes
from astroid.builder import AstroidBuilder
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session


def register(_linter):
    pass

def transform(cls):
    if cls.name == 'scoped_session':
        builder = AstroidBuilder(MANAGER)
        module_node = builder.module_build(sys.modules[Session.__module__])
        session_cls_node = [
            c for c in module_node.get_children()
            if getattr(c, "type", None) == "class" and c.name == Session.__name__
        ][0]

        for prop in Session.public_methods:
            cls.locals[prop] = [
                c for c in session_cls_node.get_children() 
                if getattr(c, "type", None) == "method" and c.name == prop
            ]

MANAGER.register_transform(scoped_nodes.Class, transform)
```

And in your `.pylintrc` file:

```
load-plugins={path}.{to}.pylintplugins
```

Answer (score 5):

In the first solution in this page, following needs to be updated. Its a typo issue,

Instead of `"pylint_flask"` in this settings.json parameter(in this line:  `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask"])` it **should** be **`"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint-flask"])`**.

Comment: This is not an answer! Doing so will just **disable pylint completely** (and silently).

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to add `scoped_session` to the list of ignored classes:

```
# List of class names for which member attributes should not be checked (useful
# for classes with dynamically set attributes). This supports the use of
# qualified names.
ignored-classes=scoped_session
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is 2022.

**My solution:**

`pip install pylint-flask-sqlalchemy`

For VSCode (v2022.2.0), add below lines on `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
  "pylint.args": [
    "--load-plugins",
    "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy"
  ]
```

For terminal

```
pylint --load-plugins pylint_flask_sqlalchemy /path/{folder/file}
``
```

Answer (score 1):

The one that worked for me was switching to flake8 python linter. Below are the steps:

1. Open VSCode and run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (for Windows Users)
2. In the VSCode Search prompt, type `Python:Select Linter`. You will see a list of all Linters and select `flake8`.
3. If you do not have `flake8` installed as a VScode extension for pylint, it will prompt you to install it. Proceed and install it.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigation I was not able to make Pylint to understand this member, so I just added `query` to the `generated-members` list and the check is ignored.

It's not a perfect solution but it works.

Comment: It is the solution since `query` will only be added at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm dealing with the issue for `scoped_session`. Trivial to extend to check for more `cls` names with SQLAlchemy attributes.

```
from astroid import MANAGER
from astroid import scoped_nodes

def register(_linter):
    pass

def transform(cls):
    if cls.name == 'scoped_session':
        for prop in ['add', 'delete', 'query', 'commit', 'rollback']:
            cls.locals[prop] = [scoped_nodes.Function(prop, None)]

MANAGER.register_transform(scoped_nodes.Class, transform)
```

Adapted from https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/plugins.html . Then make sure pylint loads your plugin.

`pylint -E --load-plugins warning_plugin Lib/warnings.py`

(or load it in pylintrc)