# Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'Column' member (no-member)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, pylint

I'm currently trying to implement steam login into website. But I'm unable to get pass this error within the code. I've created the database object but it keeps showing the error I mentioned earlier. I'm not sure whether SQLAlchemy has changed or what since I used it.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

The message emitted by `pylint` is

```
E1101: Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'Column' member (no-member)
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pylint can't find SQLAlchemy query member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193025/pylint-cant-find-sqlalchemy-query-member)

Answer (score 71):

**EDIT**: After read and try [np8's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63105358/7746976) my previous answer is wrong there is a package you have to install, which is `pylint_flask_sqlalchemy`

so the answer will be

on your project directory find folder `.vscode` (if you dont have it, just create it) then create file `settings.json` and add this line

```
{
    # You have to put it in this order to make it works
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins",
        "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy",
        "pylint_flask",                 # This package is optional
    ]
}
```

You also need to have [pylint-flask-sqlalchemy](https://gitlab.anybox.cloud/rboyer/pylint_flask_sqlalchemy) and if you want to use [pylint-flask](https://github.com/jschaf/pylint-flask) install on your current python environment:

```
pip install pylint-flask-sqlalchemy
pip install pylint-flask
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I already had a .vscode/settings.json, just added this vars and worked like a charm...

Comment: Thanks. it works. This answer should be mark as answer.

Comment: This cannot work. The load module contains dashes which will result in error. You are completely disabling pyling in vscode.

Comment: Is this config missing a comma after `"pylint_flask_sqlalchemy"`?

Comment: For me, it's "pylint-flask-sqlalchemy". Works on Python 3.9.

Comment: `pylint_flask_sqlalchemy`, with underscores not dashes.

Answer (score 21):

```
pip install pylint-flask
```

In case of *Visual Studio Code*: **Open File > Preferences > Settings > Edit** in *settings.json* as below:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask"]
```

Comment: For me, this doesn't work, but the following line does: `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint-flask"]`

Comment: For me, this only worked when I entered it into my user settings: Command Palette: Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)

Comment: I also had to enable `"python.jediEnabled": true,` in order for the pylint_flask plugin to properly figure out `scoped_session.add`, `scoped_session.commit` members. I'm not sure why. Perhaps because I have my language server set to "jedi" via `"python.languageServer": "Jedi",`.

Answer (score 19):

Open the Command Palette (Command+Shift+P on macOS and Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows/Linux) and type in one of the following commands:

```
Python: Select Linter
```

Switch from PyLint to flake8 or other supported linters.

Comment: This will hide the error but will is not a solution. Potential duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193025/pylint-cant-find-sqlalchemy-query-member

Answer (score 19):

## Summary of working and non-working configurations

<sup>*It seems that this can be configured so many ways incorrectly, that I decided to write the different options down. I am assuming VS Code, but for command line or other editor, arguments and their order is the same. These were tested using the latest versions of all the packages (list in the bottom of this post)*</sup>

#### Working versions

```
# What you'll need is pylint_flask_sqlalchemy
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy"]

# You can add pylint_flask but only if it is *AFTER* pylint_flask_sqlalchemy
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy", "pylint_flask"]
```

#### Non-working versions

```
# pylint_flask does not help, but can break it (see below)
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask"]

# You can NOT add pylint_flask *BEFORE* pylint_flask_sqlalchemy
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask", "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy"]

# CAUTION: These will disable pylint silently altogether!
# Do not use dash (-) but underscore (_)!
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint-flask-sqlalchemy", "pylint-flask"]
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint-flask"]
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint-flask-sqlalchemy"]
```

## Details for those who are interested

### pylint_flask_sqlalchemy

The [pylint-flask-sqlalchemy](https://gitlab.anybox.cloud/rboyer/pylint_flask_sqlalchemy)<sup>1</sup> was created specifically to fix this<sup>2</sup>. You can enable it by adding it to `--load-plugins` of pylint. In command line this would be

```
python -m pylint --load-plugins pylint_flash_sqlalchemy <mymodule.py>
```

and in **VS Code** (Settings (JSON)):

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy"]
```

<sup>1</sup>Also mirrored to GitHub: https://github.com/anybox/pylint_flask_sqlalchemy
<sup>2</sup>See [this](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1973#issuecomment-512748934) comment on pylint Issue tracker.

### pylint_flask

[pylint-flask](https://github.com/jschaf/pylint-flask) is pylint plugin for *Flask*. It has **nothing to do with Flask-SQLAlchemy** and it *does not even try to solve the false positive issues* pylint has with Flask-SQLAlchemy<sup>3</sup>. The only possibility to use pylint-flask to "make the errors disappear" is to load it with erroneusly with dashes, which makes the whole pylint to be disabled.

It seems that pylint-flask must be loaded *after* pylint-flas-sqlalchemy; I tested with my setup, and for some reason

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask", "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy"]
```

will **not work**, but

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy", "pylint_flask"]
```

will. So the order of loading plugins matters.

<sup><sup>3</sup> See the code for yourself: [pylint-flask source](https://github.com/jschaf/pylint-flask/blob/master/pylint_flask/__init__.py) & [pylint-flask-sqlaclhemy source](https://github.com/anybox/pylint_flask_sqlalchemy/blob/master/pylint_flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py)</sup>

#### Caution: Do not remove your linting accidentally

As the documentation of [pylint-flask](https://github.com/jschaf/pylint-flask) and [pylint-flask-sqlalchemy](https://gitlab.anybox.cloud/rboyer/pylint_flask_sqlalchemy) says, the names in the argument `--load-plugins` should be **written with underscores**; If you use

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint-flask", "pylint-flask-sqlalchemy"]
```

in VS Code, *the errors will be gone, but so will be all of your linting as the pylint crashes silently in the background.*

#### Installing pylint-flask-sqlalchemy

```
pip install pylint-flask-sqlalchemy
```

#### Used versions

```
Flask                   1.1.2  
Flask-SQLAlchemy        2.4.4 
pylint                  2.5.3
pylint-flask            0.6
pylint-flask-sqlalchemy 0.2.0
```

#### See also

- Discussion on pylint GitHub issue: "[Problem with Flask-SQLAlchemy, cannot find valid and existing property in SQLAlchemy object.](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1973)"

Comment: This is the most complete answer and should be accepted. Order is critical

Answer (score 13):

I've just encountered this issue. Neither of the suggested solutions worked for me, but the following does.

First, install these modules:

```
pip install pylint-flask
pip install pylint-flask-sqlalchemy
```

Then, in *Visual Studio Code*, you need to add the following to your `settings.json` file:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint-flask", "pylint-flask-sqlalchemy"]
```

Comment: TIP: If it doesn't seem to take effect, try reloading Visual Studio Code (Command Palette > Developer > Reload Window).

Answer (score 6):

For Windows, this works: In case of Visual Studio Code: Open File > Preferences > Settings > Edit in settings.json ->
and add this code after comma below existing settings:

```
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins",
        "pylint-flask"
    ]
```

1. [image: First step]
2. [image: Second step]

Comment: Dashes in `--load-module`  cause the pylint to crash and therefore disable it.