# Instance of relationship has no append member pylint : VS Code

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, visual-studio-code, pylint

Pylint is throwing an error on a member that works when I run the code. How to remove this error? The following code shows on which line the error is coming.

```
Class User(db.Model):
    # ...

    following = db.relationship(
            ... #Some parameters
            )

    def follow(self, user):
        if not self.is_following(user):
            self.following.append(user).   # ---- ERROR


    def is_following(self, user):
        if user.id is None:
            return False
        return self.following.filter_by(
            followed_by_id=user.id).first() is not None
```

On trying to `append` users. I am thrown an error by pylint in VS Code saying.

> Instance of 'relationship' has no 'append' member pylint(no-member)

1. How can I eliminate this error.
2. Is there any special Intellisense for sqlAlchemy?

**Note:** adding `db.relationship.*` in pyLintArgs after --generated-members is also not removing the error

Comment: Note: adding db.relationship.* in pyLintArgs  --generated-members also not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'Column' member (no-member)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975234/instance-of-sqlalchemy-has-no-column-member-no-member)

Comment: It tries to answer it. But doesn't solve it. I solved it with a workaround though. I had to import Relationship from SQLAlchemy and then use `Relationship` in the code instead of directly using `db.relationship`

Comment: I was talking about the second answer; installing `pylint-flask`

Comment: Yes, I had tried that earlier as well but it still does not solve that problem.