# Why dont i get python flask sqlalchemy autocompletion?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, vscode-python

Why dont i get python flask sqlalchemy autocompletion? I already followed [Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'Column' member (no-member)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975234/instance-of-sqlalchemy-has-no-column-member-no-member) this guide and it still doesnt work. I have used both user and workspace settings. My global user settings.json contains the following:

```
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--load-plugins",
    "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy",
    "pylint_flask"
  ],
```

and my app.py has the following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    completed = db. // doesnt autocomplete "Column"

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```